# Strange rendering across browsers

Tags: windows, internet, browser

Suddenly getting strange rendering of some pages (iGoogle for example) regardless of browser. Some sites, like Reddit render fine.

Clearly independent of browser, but not sure what's up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a broken font to me

Comment: Or problems with the [font cache](http://www.ascendercorp.com/support/#cache) or a symptom your computer is running low on memory. Try restarting the computer.